# Why does Yelp v2 Search by Phone API return (400) bad request?

Tags: c#, api, webforms, yelp

I am trying to upgrade to the latest Yelp API v2. I have implemented the v1 API, which has been working for years.

The URI I am passing: "http://api.yelp.com/v2/phone_search?phone=2127507100&cc=US"

(I tried it without the cc=US first).

The error message: "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."
(Inner Exception is null)

Yelp v1 is working fine and I am certain the daily limit has not been reached.

Here is the C# code:

```
    public Stream GetYelpResponse(string uri)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
            webRequest.Timeout = 60 * 1000;
            webRequest.Method = "GET";

            using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    return stream;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Util.WriteDBLog("GetYelpResponse" + uri, ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I posted this question on the Yelp forum, but haven't received a single response.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: this should be https://, here is a  sample c# from their site: https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/csharp/YelpAPI/Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

Check with URI/URL passing the request with the server. Since server won't respond for improper URL.

Refer below link

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yelp-developer-support/wcMrGlOa1bQ